# xv-6 make is showing up to date even with changes

Tags: linux, makefile, operating-system, xv6

I was playing around xv6 code, I changed the printf content in `ls.c` command, when I executed `make`, it showed that xv6 is already up to date

But the changes I did in `ls` command were indeed showing changes I am not able to get it why

Comment: There is no way to help you with the information you've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ls` is part of user programs (in `vx6-public`, I don't know with `xv6-riscv`), since a simple `make` only build the kernel, that is normal that `ls` is not build again.

To build user programs, type `make fs.img` or `make qemu`